# Logging into ElasticSearch with Serilog in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: elasticsearch, asp.net-web-api, serilog

I am trying to log into Elasticsearch in one of my ASP.NET Web API project using Serilog, but unfortunately, I can't find the logs in Kibana.

```cs
public class Logger
{
    private readonly ILogger _localLogger;

    public Logger()
    {
        ElasticsearchSinkOptions options = new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri("xxx"))
        {
            IndexFormat = "log-myservice-dev",
            AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
            ModifyConnectionSettings = (c) => c.BasicAuthentication("yyy", "zzz"),
            NumberOfShards = 2,
            NumberOfReplicas = 0
        };

        _localLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                            .MinimumLevel.Information()
                            .WriteTo.File(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/logs/log-.txt"), rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                            .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(options)
                            .CreateLogger();
    }

    public void LogError(string error)
    {
        _localLogger.Error(error);
    }

    public void LogInformation(string information)
    {
        _localLogger.Information(information);
    }
}
```

I can see the logs in the file specified above, just not in Elasticsearch. So, I am wondering is there is any way I can debug why it failed to log into Elasticsearch? I am also open to using other logging framework to log into Elasticsearch.

*The credentials and url for Elasticsearch are valid as I have implemented this in my other AWS Lambda project (.net core).

Comment: Have you tried to look for error -> https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch#handling-errors
I believe you can log such error locally to debug

Comment: Yeap, that did the trick.

Comment: so what is the issue then XD or did you already fix it ?

Comment: The issue was with not being able to establish a HTTPS connection to elasticsearch. Added the error message + solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see exactly what went wrong, the easiest way is to write into console, and in case of ASP.NET project, it will be Debug.WriteLine. So the code to see what went wrong would be

```cs
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));

ElasticsearchSinkOptions options = new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri("xxx"))
{
         IndexFormat = "log-myservice-dev",
         AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
         ModifyConnectionSettings = (c) => c.BasicAuthentication("yyy", "zzz"),
         NumberOfShards = 2,
         NumberOfReplicas = 1,
         EmitEventFailure = EmitEventFailureHandling.WriteToSelfLog,
         MinimumLogEventLevel = Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information
};
```

The following error message was retrieved from the output console.

> Failed to create the template.
> Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: The request was
> aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.. Call: Status code
> unknown from: HEAD /_template/serilog-events-template --->
> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create
> SSL/TLS secure channel.

The issue is quite clear cut. Added the following in my logger class constructor helped with the issue.

```cs
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Hope it helps others that encounter issue trying to use Serilog to log into Elasticsearch for .Net Framework.